# Hotlinking to help points

Tags: feature-request

The help section is often the place that new users need to go to correct problems with their questions.

It would be helpful if each point had an anchor so that it could be # linked directly. This way we could direct new users precisely where they need to look to find out why their question doesn't fit our format.

Comment: Note that there are 'magic links' such that `[help/on-topic]` becomes a link to the [help/on-topic]... though this doesn't go to specific subjections of the page.

Comment: Pretty sure I've seen this suggested before, though I can't find the duplicate at the moment.

Comment: Note the [already supported shorthand links](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) in the editing help - comment formatting page.  That said, could you give a better example of what you want to link to that might be an anchor?

Comment: Well, earlier I had the need to direct a first time poster to the help center > section 2 > point 1. That's where we ask that debugging questions be specific and provide the minimum amount of information to reproduce the error. But I had to write that out and hope he knew where I meant. Perhaps the magic links could be extended?

Comment: if they did not read Section 2, Point 1, I'd bet they did not read Section 1, 2 or 3 and directing them to the base page is enough.

Comment: @Plutonix: If you direct them to section 2, point 1, they have rather less text to read than if you ask them to read the whole page, so perhaps they're more willing to read it.  Or at least if they don't, they have fewer excuses and we can dispose of them more quickly.

Comment: To Jeffrey Bosboom's point, the small amount of knowledge they gain could act as a boon towards reading the rest of the document, assuming they're the kind of people that wish to participate in the community in a compliant manner.

Comment: I think that could come across as picyune *Aha I direct you to Section 4 <blah blah blah>; -1 for not adhering to article 3 there.*  The fact is they are presented with all that when they join and before they can ask their first question.  Some of those pages need **Bold Text** warning them that the rules are enforced here, policed by thousands, and we are not just another forum-anarchy and they can get banned for not complying.  Its too warm and fuzzy as it is (IMO).

Comment: Well there's a new word. But the fact is that this is a common case, and new users need much reminding. I don't think that the community would be more likely than they are currently to take such an attitude. Those who have that outlook already direct new users in a _picyune_ manner.

Comment: Even the [magic-link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-links) is sub-optimal. IMO, it should render [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for `[help/on-topic]`, not [help/on-topic]...